# What's the command to migrate images too?

Tags: migrations

I'm currently using Drush to migrate a Drupal 7 site to a fresh copy of Drupal 8. Everything is migrated except the image fields.

I get thousands of these warnings with different ID numbers.

> [warning] Missing file with ID 26. ImageItem.php:329
>   [warning] Missing file with ID 26. ImageItem.php:329
>   [warning] Missing file with ID 26. ImageItem.php:329

I'm also using WAMP to locally migrate the site and maybe I'm typing the destination public file path incorrectly. Here's some of the commands I tried.

- `drush migrate-upgrade --legacy-db-key=migrate --legacy-root=/wamp64/www/d7 --configure-only`
- `drush migrate-upgrade --legacy-db-key=migrate --legacy-root=c:/wamp64/www/d7 --configure-only`
- `drush migrate-upgrade --legacy-db-key=migrate --legacy-root=/www/d7 --configure-only`
- `drush migrate-upgrade --legacy-db-key=migrate --legacy-root=/d7 --configure-only`

What's the command to migrate images too?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you see a `d7_file` migration generated after your  `drush migrate-upgrade` command? You need to have run the `d7_file` migration before image `fid` references can resolve to their new values.

Comment: You also need to supply the path to your D7 installation where the files reside. In the file migrations generated by migrate upgrade this appears under source: constants: source_base_path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys for helping out! I figured it out and migrated all my images and files. Here's what I did for anyone who has the same problem:

I'm was using WAMP and WSL Ubuntu, I was setting the legacy--path incorrectly so my source_base_path was incorrect. I had to open up migrate_plus.migration.upgrade_d7_file.yml and used the correct path. Then I ran drush config-import to import the updated file and then ran the migrate.

Here's my file:

```
uuid: 2a4842a5-0869-4984-aaae-68d6c5814f5d
langcode: en
status: true
dependencies: {  }
id: upgrade_d7_file
class: Drupal\migrate\Plugin\Migration
field_plugin_method: null
cck_plugin_method: null
migration_tags:
  - 'Drupal 7'
  - Content
migration_group: migrate_drupal_7
label: 'Public files'
source:
  plugin: d7_file
  scheme: public
  constants:
    source_base_path: /mnt/c/wamp64/www/d7
process:
  fid:
    -
      plugin: get
      source: fid
  filename:
    -
      plugin: get
      source: filename
  source_full_path:
    -
      plugin: concat
      delimiter: /
      source:
        - constants/source_base_path
        - filepath
    -
      plugin: urlencode
  uri:
    -
      plugin: file_copy
      source:
        - '@source_full_path'
        - uri
  filemime:
    -
      plugin: get
      source: filemime
  status:
    -
      plugin: get
      source: status
  created:
    -
      plugin: get
      source: timestamp
  changed:
    -
      plugin: get
      source: timestamp
  uid:
    -
      plugin: get
      source: uid
destination:
  plugin: 'entity:file'
  source_base_path: /mnt/c/wamp64/www/d7/sites/default/files/
migration_dependencies:
  required: {  }
  optional: {  }
```

Comment: Does anyone have a reference to how to create the "migrate_plus.migration.upgrade_d7_file.yml" file? A drush config:export does not seem to be creating it for me, and I'm seeing the d7_file migration operate as if the legacy-root is not set.